# Write a webpack plugin to push plugin into consumer app

Tags: webpack, plugins

I wrote a webpack plugin called `customModuleFederationPlugin`, to inject `ModuleFederationPlugin` with some configuration into the consumer app. By output of `compiler.options.plugins`, it shows that the plugin has been successfully injected, but when I run `npm run dev`, it shows error 'can't resolve hostapp/exposed'. But it was working normally before I used my custom plugin, so I don't think it has anything to do with the host app configuration. My speculation is that I've used the wrong compiler hook

the plugin code:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container

require('dotenv').config()

class CustomModuleFederationPlugin{
  constructor(options){
      this.targetDependency = options.targetDependency;
      this.currentApp = options.appName
  }

  apply(compiler){
      compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tap('CustomModuleFederationPlugin', (compiler) =>{
          console.log("hello from Custom Module Federation plugin");
          const deps = require(`${compiler.options.context}/../package.json`).dependencies;

          compiler.options.plugins.push(new ModuleFederationPlugin(
              {
                  name: process.env.LOCAL_DEV ? this.currentApp : "localapp",
                  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
                  remotes: {
                    appshell: process.env.LOCAL_DEV
                      ? "appshell@http://localhost:8090/remoteEntry.js"
                      : "appshell@/app/appshell/remoteEntry.js?[window.cacheHash]",
                  },
                  exposes: { "./Main": "./" },
                  shared: {
                    ...deps,
                    react: {
                      singleton: true,
                      requiredVersion: deps.react,
                    },
                    "react-dom": {
                      singleton: true,
                      requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                    },
                  },
                }
          ));
          console.log("plugin after: ",compiler.options.plugins[2]);
      },
        compiler.hooks.normalModuleFactory.tap('CustomModuleFederationPlugin', (normalModuleFactory) =>{
          normalModuleFactory.hooks.afterResolve.tap('CustomModuleFederationPlugin', data =>{
            if(data.dependencies){
              data.dependencies = data.dependencies.filter(dependency => {return dependency.request !== this.targetDependency});
            }
          }
          )})
      )
  }
}

module.exports = CustomModuleFederationPlugin;
```

In consumer app `webpack.config.debug.js`:

```
const CustomModuleFederationPlugin = require('custommodulefederationplugin')
plugins: [
    new CustomModuleFederationPlugin({targetDependency: "ui-library", appName: "kpartnerapi"}),
...
]
```

error in the consumer app:

```
plugins: [
    new CustomModuleFederationPlugin({targetDependency: "ui-library", appName: "kpartnerapi"}),
```

Since the error only occurs after I used my plugin, all the imports are correct.